# Como adicionar um ProgressBar em um PagerAdapter?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Tenho um ViewPager que utiliza um PagerAdapter para fazer um slide de imagens. Na minha classe que extende PagerAdapter eu tenho uma AsyncTask que carrega as imagens da internet e joga no ImageView. Como eu posso colocar um ProgressBar spinner para ficar rodando enquanto a imagem não carrega?

Tentei dessa forma, mas não exibe o ProgressBar na tela:

```
...

ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, 
            android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

linearLayout.addView(progressBar);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Na minha classe que extente PagerAdapter, fiz o seguinte:

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout =  new RelativeLayout(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    container.addView(relativeLayout);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    relativeLayout.addView(imageView);

    RelativeLayout progressLayout =  new RelativeLayout(context);
    progressLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    progressLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    relativeLayout.addView(progressLayout);


    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressLayout.addView(progressBar);

    try {
        new ImageLoadTask(imagesUrl[position], imageView , progressBar).execute();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Error" , e.getMessage());
    }

    return relativeLayout;
}//instantiateItem
```

Agora é só trabalahar o ProgressBar na AsyncTask.